# Can I change this sentence into passive voice?

Tags: grammar

If I have a sentence like this "We are going to join in the trip to New York", can I change it into passive voice?

Comment: Please add more detail to explain what you think the passive of this would be, and why you think it may be correct or incorrect?

Comment: And why you have this question. How did it come up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## TL;DR: You shouldn't, but you can

#### Very awkward and inadvisable, if technically possible

To use the [passive voice](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/passive_voice.htm), one takes a noun and puts a conjugation of to be and a [past participle](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/past_participles.htm) after it, then, optionally, "by" and whatever actually does the action.

Some examples of the passive voice are:

> The question **is read**.
>
> The answers **are written** by them.
>
> They **are viewed** by us.

**For your sentence, this is what the passive voice would be:**

> The trip to New York is going to be joined in by us.

Yikes...**this is really awkward, and the normal [active voice](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/active_voice.htm) works much better.** In real conversations, I would always use the active voice with this.

Comment: How can I improve this?